# Facebook Graph API - format of field property

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, text-formatting

[Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) is using the field property in QueryString to fetch data that is provided. Is this a standard text format of some sort or an own invention from Facebook?

For example: fields=about,address,accounts{about,access_token}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textformat: [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/)

Reference to [Facebook GraphQL on github](https://github.com/facebook/graphql)